# How To Read HTML code as XML and get the output like the sample in sql?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, xml

I have HTML code stored in the data base, and I want to read it as XML.

My codes:

http://rextester.com/RMEHO89992

This is an example of the HTML code I have:

```
<div>
  <section>
       <h4>
         <span> A </span>
        </h4>
        <ul>
           <li>
              <span> Ab</span>
                     AD
              <span> AC </span>
           </li>
           <li>
              <span> Ag</span>
              <span> AL </span>
           </li>
        </ul>
        <h4>
              <span> B </span>
       </h4>
       <ul>
           <li>
              <span> Bb</span>
                     BD
              <span> BC </span>
           </li>
           <li>
              <span> Bg</span>
              <span> BL </span>
           </li>
        </ul>
   </section>
</div>
```

and this is an example of the output I need:

```
Category         Selection        Value                    
---------        ---------        ------------             
A                Ab               AD                  
A                Ag               AL                       
B                Bb               BD                   
B                Bg               BL
```

I need to get the value inside the `<h4>` tag as a `Category`, the first `<span>` tag as Selection, and the rest of the values as a concatenated string.

I've tried the following query:

```
SELECT 
    (  isnull(t.v.value('(h4/span/span[1]/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)'),'') 
     + isnull(t.v.value('(h4/span/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)'),'')
     + isnull(t.v.value('(h4/span/span[2]/text())[2]','nvarchar(max)'),'')
    ) AS [Category],
    (  isnull(c.g.value('(span[1]/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)'),'')
     + isnull(c.g.value('(span[1]/span/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)'),'')
     + isnull(c.g.value('(span[1]/text())[2]','nvarchar(max)'),'')
    ) AS [Selection],
    (  isnull(c.g.value('(span[2]/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)'),'')
     + isnull(c.g.value('(span[2]/span/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)'),'')
     + isnull(c.g.value('(span[2]/text())[2]','nvarchar(max)'),'')
    ) AS [Value]
FROM @htmlXML.nodes('div/section') as t(v)
CROSS APPLY t.v.nodes('./ul/li') AS c(g)
```

**and** :

```
SELECT 
       t.v.value('.','nvarchar(max)')
       ,
     --( isnull(t.v.value('(h4/span/span[1]/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)'),'')+isnull(t.v.value('(h4/span/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)'),'')+isnull(t.v.value('(h4/span/span[2]/text())[2]','nvarchar(max)'),''))AS [Category],

          ( isnull(c.g.value('(span[1]/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)'),'')+isnull(c.g.value('(span[1]/span/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)'),'')+isnull(c.g.value('(span[1]/text())[2]','nvarchar(max)'),''))AS [Selection]

           ,
         ( isnull(c.g.value('(span[2]/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)'),'')+isnull(c.g.value('(span[2]/span/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)'),'')+isnull(c.g.value('(span[2]/text())[2]','nvarchar(max)'),''))AS [Value]
    FROM    @htmlXML.nodes('div/section/h4/span') as t(v)
    CROSS APPLY @htmlXML.nodes('div/section/ul/li') AS c(g)
```

But it only gets the first category, and doesn't get all the values togheter.

```
Category         Selection        Value
---------        ---------        ------------
A                Ab               AC 
B                Ab               AC 
A                Ag               AL
B                Ag               AL 
A                Bb               BC
B                Bb               BC 
A                Bg               BL 
B                Bg               BL
```

There can be N categories, and the values might or might not be inside `<span>` tags.
How can I get all the categories with their corresponding value?
or get :

```
category              h4 number
--------            -----------
 A                     1
 B                     2
```

> - 1 ,mean = h4 first , 2 ,mean = h4 second

```
 ul number         Selection        Value                    
    ---------        ---------        ------------             
    1                Ab               AD                  
    1                Ag               AL                       
    2                Bb               BD                   
    2                Bg               BL
```

relation between column ul number and h4 number. i cannt.

Comment: Are you sure the expected result is correct? Shouldn't it be `AD AC` for the first row in the third column?

Comment: I am trying to establish communication between nodes` h4` and ` ul `.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not exactly elegant but seems to do the job.

```
DECLARE @X XML = REPLACE(REPLACE(@S, '<h4>', '<foo><h4>'), '</ul>', '</ul></foo>')

SELECT Category = x.value('../../h4[1]/span[1]', 'varchar(10)'),
       Selection = x.value('descendant-or-self::text()[1]', 'varchar(10)'),
       Value = REPLACE(
                REPLACE(
                 REPLACE(
                  LTRIM(
                   RTRIM(
                    REPLACE(
                     REPLACE(
                      CAST(x.x.query('fn:data(descendant-or-self::text()[fn:position() > 1])') AS VARCHAR(MAX))
                     , char(10), '')
                    , char(13), '')
                   )
                  )
                 , '  ', ' |')
                , '| ', '')
               , '|', '')
FROM   @X.nodes('div/section/foo/ul/li') x(x)
ORDER  BY Category,
          Selection
```

[Which returns](http://rextester.com/ACN57563)

```
+----------+-----------+-------+
| Category | Selection | Value |
+----------+-----------+-------+
|  A       |  Ab       | AD AC |
|  A       |  Ag       | AL    |
|  B       |  Bb       | BD BC |
|  B       |  Bg       | BL    |
+----------+-----------+-------+
```

I'm assuming this is what you want as the desired results table in the question does not return the "rest of the values as a concatenated string"

Answer (score 14):

> I am trying to establish communication between nodes`h4` and `ul`.

You can use the `<<` and `>>` operator to check if a node is before or after another node in document order. Combine that with a predicate on position, `[1]`, to get the first occurrence also in document order.

```sql
select H4.X.value('(span/text())[1]', 'varchar(10)') as Section,
       UL.X.query('.') as UL
from @X.nodes('/div/section/h4') as H4(X)
  cross apply H4.X.nodes('(let $h4 := . (: Save current h4 node :)
                           return /div/section/ul[$h4 << .])[1]') as UL(X);
```

[rextester:](http://rextester.com/XWE22167)

`<<` and `>>` are called [Node Order Comparison Operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190935.aspx#Anchor_3)

If you have an XML fragment like this:

```xml
<N1>1</N1>
<N2>2</N2>
<N3>3</N3>
<N4>4</N4>
<N5>5</N5>
```

you can get all nodes before the first occurrence of `N3` with this query:

```sql
select @X.query('/*[. << /N3[1]]');
```

Result:

```xml
<N1>1</N1>
<N2>2</N2>
```

`/*` will give you all root nodes. What is enclosed in `[]` is a predicate. `.` is the current node and `/N3[1]` is the first N3 node in document order at the root level. So from each root node you get the nodes that precede `N3`.

Here is almost the same query, only you get the nodes that *follow* the first `N3` node:

```sql
select @X.query('/*[. >> /N3[1]]');
```

```xml
<N4>4</N4>
<N5>5</N5>
```

To only get the first node after the first `N3` node, you add the predicate `[1]`:

```sql
select @X.query('/*[. >> /N3[1]][1]');
```

```xml
<N4>4</N4>
```